# Printer delivery extension and empty report

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have implemented a printer delivery extension based on MS example in SSRS 2005.

Everything works fine, however, I run into a problem when the dataset is empty. I get a single blank page. If there is no data I would rather not send the job to the printer.

Anyone have any experience with this or ideas how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using a technique suggested by someone else. Unfortunately, I can't find that post now to give them proper credit.

My solution is to set up a data driven subscription passing the only parameter I have(printer name). The query used in the subscription joins against a key table in the report so that if there is no data there is no printer to print to thus nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

maybe run the sql to get a row count, and only print if its not zero?

Comment: How would I do that in the printer delivery extension (dll)?